# MultiDex Error AllDebugClassesForMultiDex

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-volley, build.gradle, gradlew

Unable to build project while we using the

> PayPalHereSDK-1.6.1.1-release and 
>   Volley

libraries.

Am using the Android Studio to 1.5.1 version. I found in project gradle file error in line

**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.

> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/volley/AuthFailureError.class**

Thanks in an advance..!